# Need to get set of numbers in cyclic order - Python

Tags: python

I am writing some python script to generate JSON. I constructed the jSON successfully. but stuck in getting selecting number in cyclic order.
let us say, i have a list of 1,2,3,4,5. I need to select first 4 numbers (1,2,3,4) here for first first item and 2,3,4,5 for second and 3,4,5,1 for third and it should go on till 30 times.

```
import json
import random
json_dict = {}
number = []
brokers = [1,2,3,4,5]

json_dict["version"] = version
json_dict["partitions"] = [{"topic": "topic1", "name": i,"replicas": 
random.choice(brokers)} for i in range(0, 30)]

with open("output.json", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(json_dict, outfile, indent=4)
```

Output

```
"version": "1", 
"partitions": [
    {
        "topic": "topic1", 
        "name": 0, 
        "replicas": 1,2,3,4
    }, 
    {
        "topic": "topic1", 
        "name": 1, 
        "replicas": 2,3,4,5
    }, 
    {
        "topic": "topic1", 
        "name": 3, 
        "replicas": 3,4,5,1
```

Anyway, how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get a cyclic elements from your `brokers list` you can use `deque` from `collections` module and do a `deque.rotation(-1)` like this example:

```
from collections import deque

def grouper(iterable, elements, rotations):
    if elements > len(iterable):
        return []

    b = deque(iterable)
    for _ in range(rotations):
        yield list(b)[:elements]
        b.rotate(-1)

brokers = [1,2,3,4,5]
# Pick 4 elements from brokers and yield 30 cycles
cycle = list(grouper(brokers, 4, 30))
print(cycle)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5, 1], [4, 5, 1, 2], [5, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5, 1], [4, 5, 1, 2], [5, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5, 1], [4, 5, 1, 2], [5, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5, 1], [4, 5, 1, 2], [5, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5, 1], [4, 5, 1, 2], [5, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5, 1], [4, 5,1, 2], [5, 1, 2, 3]]
```

Also, this is a way how to implement this solution to your final dict:

```
# in this example i'm using only 5 cycles
cycles = grouper(brokers, 4, 5)
partitions = [{"topic": "topic1", "name": i, "replicas": cycle_elem} for i, cycle_elem in zip(range(5), cycles)]
final_dict = {"version": "1", "partitions": partitions}

print(final_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'partitions': [{'name': 0, 'replicas': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'topic': 'topic1'}, {'name': 1, 'replicas': [2, 3, 4, 5], 'topic': 'topic1'}, {'name': 2, 'replicas': [3, 4, 5, 1], 'topic': 'topic1'}, {'name': 3, 'replicas': [4, 5, 1, 2], 'topic': 'topic1'}, {'name': 4, 'replicas': [5, 1, 2, 3], 'topic': 'topic1'}], 'version': '1'}
```

Comment: i am gng with @Chiheb Nexus answer. Thanks Dude.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't hesitate to comment to this answer if you need more help or if you don't understand how this solution work. Happy coding :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a purely procedural solution which also adds flexibility of selecting any number of groups, of any size (even bigger than the original 'brokers' list) with any offset:

```
def get_subgroups(groups, base, size, offset=1):
    # cover the group size > len(base) case by expanding the base
    # this step is completely optional if your group size will never be bigger
    base *= -(-size // len(base))

    result = []  # storage for our groups
    base_size = len(base)  # no need to call len() all the time
    current_offset = 0  # tracking current cycle offset
    for i in range(groups):  # use xrange() on Python 2.x instead
        tail = current_offset + size  # end index for our current slice
        end = min(tail, base_size)  # normalize to the base size
        group = base[current_offset:end] + base[:tail - end]  # get our slice
        result.append(group)  # append it to our result storage
        current_offset = (current_offset + offset) % base_size  # increase our current offset
    return result

brokers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

print(get_subgroups(5, brokers, 4))  # 5 groups of size 4, with default offset
# prints: [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5, 1], [4, 5, 1, 2], [5, 1, 2, 3]]

print(get_subgroups(3, brokers, 7, 2))  # 3 groups of size 7, with offset 2
# prints: [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1]]
```

And it does it in a O(N) time with a single loop.

If you're planning to run this on a very large generator, you can turn `get_subgroups()` function into a generator by forgoing the `result` collection and doing `yield group` instead of `result.append(group)`. That way you can call it in a loop as: `for group in get_subgroups(30, broker, 4):` and store the `group` in whatever structure you want.

**UPDATE**

If memory is not an issue, we can optimize (processing-wise) this even more by expanding the whole `base` (or `brokers` in your case) to fit the whole set:

```
def get_subgroups(groups, base, size, offset=1):  # warning, heavy memory usage!
    base *= -(-(offset * groups + size) // len(base))
    result = []  # storage for our groups
    current_offset = 0  # tracking current cycle offset
    for i in range(groups):  # use xrange() on Python 2.x instead
        result.append(base[current_offset:current_offset+size])
        current_offset += offset
    return result
```

Or we can make it even faster with list comprehension if we don't need the ability to turn it into a generator:

```
def get_subgroups(groups, base, size, offset=1):  # warning, heavy memory usage!
    base *= -(-(offset * groups + size) // len(base))
    return [base[i:i+size] for i in range(0, groups * offset, offset)]
    # as previously mentioned, use xrange() on Python 2.x instead
```

Comment: Your solution is about 3 times faster than mine. Good appproach! +1

Comment: `itertools` are generally a hog and don't leave much room for optimization - but what you lose in speed you gain in productivity and not having to reinvent the wheel ;). btw. if memory is not an issue, pure expansion of the `broker` array to cover all the cycles and then just looping through it would be blazingly fast... I'll update my answer to cover it for posterity ;)

Comment: Well, the first and trivial way is using `itertools.cycle`, in my answer i'm using `deque` because it's easy to use it and it's more verbose than dealing with `itertools.cycle`. Your approach here is quite efficient too.

Comment: Ooops, I thought yours was using a regular culprit for this kind of data cycling. Mea culpa.

Comment: @ChihebNexus - if you still have your timing code / data set, check the updated example, it should kill it performance wise...

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty cool problem, and I think I have a pretty cool solution:

```
items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[(items * 2)[x:x+4] for i in range(30) for x in [i % len(items)]]
```

which gives

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4],
 [2, 3, 4, 5],
 [3, 4, 5, 1],
 [4, 5, 1, 2],
 [5, 1, 2, 3],
 [1, 2, 3, 4],
 [2, 3, 4, 5],
 [3, 4, 5, 1],
 [4, 5, 1, 2],
 [5, 1, 2, 3],
 [1, 2, 3, 4],
 [2, 3, 4, 5],
 [3, 4, 5, 1],
 [4, 5, 1, 2],
 [5, 1, 2, 3],
 [1, 2, 3, 4],
 [2, 3, 4, 5],
 [3, 4, 5, 1],
 [4, 5, 1, 2],
 [5, 1, 2, 3],
 [1, 2, 3, 4],
 [2, 3, 4, 5],
 [3, 4, 5, 1],
 [4, 5, 1, 2],
 [5, 1, 2, 3],
 [1, 2, 3, 4],
 [2, 3, 4, 5],
 [3, 4, 5, 1],
 [4, 5, 1, 2],
 [5, 1, 2, 3]]
```

What this is doing is taking your set of things and appending it to itself (`items * 2` -> `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3 ,4, 5]`), and then picking a starting place (`x`) by taking our loop iteration (`i`) and modulating it (probably not the right word) by the number of items we have (`i in [x % len(items)]`).

Comment: You don't need to double the `items` list on each loop - do it outside of the list comprehension construct.